# Is there a "best" representative of a rational function so it is regular in its domian?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

So these are from my lecture notes:
[image]

[image]

Note that we have defined regular functions on $X$ to be the restriction of some polynomial. Now my question is: does there exist a "best" representative of a rational function so the domain of this representative is in fact the domian of the rational mapping. So for example, if we have a rational mapping $\phi=1/x$ between $A^1$ to itself, at different points, we can multiply the numerator and denominator by a factor like $ (x-p)$ and this representative is still the same rational mapping $\phi$ but this representative is not defined at the point $p$. But the representative $1/x$ is the "best" in the sense that its domain is the same as the domain of $\phi$. So I hope my question is not too confusing. It's simply that based on the definition of a rational function, it sounds like we need to vary our representatives $f,g$ at different points of our domain, so I just want to know if can find one "best" representative that gives us our whole domain so that we can just view $\phi$ as $f/g$ so we don't have to vary them at different points of our domain.

Comment: In general no. Consider the affine variety defined by $xy-zw=0$ in four space, with coordinates $x,y,z,w$. Consider the rational function $x/z= w/y$.

Comment: @Mohan do you want to post that as an answer?